# Telegram Bot getUpdates VS setWebhook

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to develop a bot for a business!
I don't know that using [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getupdates) method for develop a windows desktop application and run that on vps (by https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot library)
or using [setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#setwebhook) method to develop bot with php!

Which one is better in terms of speed and etc?
And what are some other differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not matter you want to use which kind of server side applications.
Typically `getUpdates` used for debugging. For publishing your bots, you need to using the `Webhook`. [See this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks).

> getUpdates is a pull mechanism, setWebhook is push.
>   There are some advantages of using a Webhook over getUpdates:
>
> 1. Avoids your bot having to ask for updates frequently.
> 2. Avoids the need for some kind of polling mechanism in your code.

Answer (score 2):

A popular library `python-telegram-bot` builds most examples around polling through `getUpdates` and later moves on to webhooks, cautiously:

> You should have a good reason to switch from polling to a webhook.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks

My personal take is that webhook is a cleaner way to receive event information form Telegram API (POST request goes from Telegram right after after the event, no need for idle looping), but it needs more infrastructure:

- expose a public API endpoint
- application must be ready to porcess this call to an endpoint

Most tutorials focus on how to get a bot example running quickly and do that on a local machine, so `getUpdates` is a natural choice for this.