# deploy telegram bot on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, telegram-bot

I want to learn how to create telegram bot but I have trouble on deploying it on the cloud. I kept getting this error on Heroku log

```
2021-11-01T16:51:38.071120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/2xxxxxXXxx:AAAAAAAAxxxx-xxx" host=xxxx-Xxxx-xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=ed02154c-af96-44b7-af50-0ad1d8891f8f fwd="91.108.6.83" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https

2021-11-01T16:51:38.076047+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: bot.processUpdate is not a function

2021-11-01T16:51:38.076210+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/index.js:18:6
```

here is my index.js

```
// DEPENDENCIES
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();

const bot = require('./bot');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello from the Bot API.' });
});
// TELEGRAM WEBHOOK - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook
app.post(`/${process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN}`, (req, res) => {
    bot.processUpdate(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'ok' });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`\n\nServer running on port ${port}.\n\n`);
});
```

and here is my bot.js

```
//dependency
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

//bot token
const token = process.env.TELEGRAM_TOKEN;
//initialize bot
var bot;

// if production env, we use webhooks
// https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook
// https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+setWebHook
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    bot = new TelegramBot(token);
    bot.setWebHook(process.env.HEROKU_URL + bot.token);
    console.log('**** BOT initiated ***** ');
} else {
    // otherwise, we use polling
    // differences between webhooks and polling:
    // https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033150/telegram-bot-getupdates-vs-setwebhook
    bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });
}

console.log(`Bot started in the ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode`);


bot.onText(/^\/say_hello (.+)$/, function (msg, match) {
    var name = match[1];
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Hello ' + name + '!').then(function () {
        // reply sent!
    });
});

bot.onText(/^\/sum((\s+\d+)+)$/, function (msg, match) {
    var result = 0;
    match[1].trim().split(/\s+/).forEach(function (i) {
        result += (+i || 0);
    })
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, result).then(function () {
        // reply sent!
    });
});
```

everything works flawlessly on local. I thought the problem was with the webhook URL at first, after spending hours I realized the log said something else. I'm using https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api and the documentation definitely still have processUpdate written but I have no idea how to test it. Since deploying on local works maybe the problem is somewhere else that I have no idea about.

Comment: nevermind. I should have followed example on github first, my problem solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exports `bot` defined in bot.js adding to that module next line

```
module.exports = bot
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.